# Extract nested JSON embedded as string in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a CSV where one of the fields is a nested JSON object, stored as a string. I would like to load the CSV into a dataframe and parse the JSON into a set of fields appended to the original dataframe; in other words, extract the contents of the JSON and make them part of the dataframe.

My CSV:

```
id|dist|json_request
1|67|{"loc":{"lat":45.7, "lon":38.9},"arrival": "Monday", "characteristics":{"body":{"color":"red", "make":"sedan"}, "manuf_year":2014}}
2|34|{"loc":{"lat":46.89, "lon":36.7},"arrival": "Tuesday", "characteristics":{"body":{"color":"blue", "make":"sedan"}, "manuf_year":2014}}
3|98|{"loc":{"lat":45.70, "lon":31.0}, "characteristics":{"body":{"color":"yellow"}, "manuf_year":2010}}
```

Note that not all keys are the same for all the rows.
I'd like it to produce a data frame equivalent to this:

```
data = {'id'     : [1, 2, 3],
        'dist'  : [67, 34, 98],
        'loc_lat': [45.7, 46.89, 45.70],
        'loc_lon': [38.9, 36.7, 31.0],
        'arrival': ["Monday", "Tuesday", "NA"],
        'characteristics_body_color':["red", "blue", "yellow"],
        'characteristics_body_make':["sedan", "sedan", "NA"],
        'characteristics_manuf_year':[2014, 2014, 2010]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

(I'm really sorry, I can't get the table itself to look sensible in SO! Please don't be mad at me, I'm a rookie :( )

### What I've tried

After a lot of futzing around, I came up with the following solution:

```
#Import data
df_raw = pd.read_csv("sample.csv", delimiter="|")

#Parsing function
def parse_request(s):
    sj = json.loads(s)
    norm = json_normalize(sj)
    return norm

#Create an empty dataframe to store results
parsed = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id'])

#Loop through and parse JSON in each row
for i in df_raw.json_request:
    parsed = parsed.append(parse_request(i))

#Merge results back onto original dataframe
df_parsed = df_raw.join(parsed)
```

This is obviously inelegant and really inefficient (would take multiple hours on the 300K rows that I have to parse). Is there a better way?

### Where I've looked

I've gone through the following related questions:
[Reading a CSV into pandas where one column is a json string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680272/reading-a-csv-into-pandas-where-one-column-is-a-json-string)
(which seems to only work for simple, non-nested JSON)

[JSON to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe)
(I borrowed parts of my solutions from this, but I can't figure out how to apply this solution across the dataframe without looping through rows)

I'm using Python 3.3 and Pandas 0.17.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's an approach that speeds things up by a factor of 10 to 100, and should allow you to read your big file in under a minute, as opposed to over an hour. The idea is to only construct a dataframe once all of the data has been read, thereby reducing the number of times memory needs to be allocated, and to only call `json_normalize` once on the entire chunk of data, rather than on each row:

```
import csv
import json

import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with open('sample.csv') as fh:
    rows = csv.reader(fh, delimiter='|')
    header = next(rows)

    # "transpose" the data. `data` is now a tuple of strings
    # containing JSON, one for each row
    idents, dists, data = zip(*rows)

data = [json.loads(row) for row in data]
df = json_normalize(data)
df['ids'] = idents
df['dists'] = dists
```

So that:

```
>>> print(df)

   arrival characteristics.body.color characteristics.body.make  \
0   Monday                        red                     sedan   
1  Tuesday                       blue                     sedan   
2      NaN                     yellow                       NaN   

   characteristics.manuf_year  loc.lat  loc.lon ids  
0                        2014    45.70     38.9   1  
1                        2014    46.89     36.7   2  
2                        2010    45.70     31.0   3
```

---

Furthermore, I looked into what `pandas`'s `json_normalize` is doing, and it's performing some deep copies that shouldn't be necessary if you're just creating a dataframe from a CSV. We can implement our own `flatten` function which takes a dictionary and "flattens" the keys, similar to what `json_normalize` does. Then we can make a generator which spits out one row of the dataframe at a time as a record. This approach is even faster:

```
def flatten(dct, separator='_'):
    """A fast way to flatten a dictionary,"""
    res = {}
    queue = [('', dct)]

    while queue:
        prefix, d = queue.pop()
        for k, v in d.items():
            key = prefix + k
            if not isinstance(v, dict):
                res[key] = v
            else:
                queue.append((key + separator, v))

    return res

def records_from_json(fh):
    """Yields the records from a file object."""
    rows = csv.reader(fh, delimiter='|')
    header = next(rows)
    for ident, dist, data in rows:
        rec = flatten(json.loads(data))
        rec['id'] = ident
        rec['dist'] = dist
        yield rec

def from_records(path):
    with open(path) as fh:
        return pd.DataFrame.from_records(records_from_json(fh))
```

---

And here are the results of a timing experiment where I artificially increased the size of your sample data by repeating rows. The number of lines is denoted by `n_rows`:

```
        method 1 (s)  method 2 (s)  original time (s)
n_rows                                               
96          0.008217      0.002971           0.362257
192         0.014484      0.004720           0.678590
384         0.027308      0.008720           1.373918
768         0.055644      0.016175           2.791400
1536        0.105730      0.030914           5.727828
3072        0.209049      0.060105          11.877403
```

Extrapolating linearly, the first method should read 300k lines in about 20 seconds, while the second method should take around 6 seconds.

Comment: @SoHei No problem! I added a second method which is even faster and updated the timings accordingly.

Comment: I've been struggling with this issue until I saw your solution. Thank you! This works great!

Comment: The solution provided by jme is really great! It solved and performed to my expectations...Thanks once again!!