# Write and read csv files with Pandas where a specific column cell value could be a list of dicts

Tags: python, pandas

After exhaustive search and trying to make it work... here I am.

Summary of what I need:
I need to create and read csv files, so I could freely manipulate the data from the files.
For example:

```
row1 = {"col1": "value1", "col2": 0.5, "col3": [{"key1": 0.2}, {"key2": 0.3}]
df = pandas.DataFrame(row1, columns=["col1", "col2", "col3"]
df.to_csv("test.csv")
```

The file that I get looks like that:

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   value1  0.5   [{'key1': 0.2}, {'key2': 0.3}]
```

After that I can read the file with:

```
df = pandas.read_csv("test.csv")
```

The problems come with cases such as `col3`. I I foolishly thought that when I convert the data frame:

```
df = list(df.T.to_dict().values())
```

I could access `col3` with:

```
for row in df:
    wanted_data = row["col3"]
```

I thought that I will get a list with two dictionaries in it.
What I actually get is a string.

How can I access `key1`, `key2` (the keys are different) and their corresponding values?
I already tried with:

```
json.loads(wanted_data)
```

But no matter what I do I get those kinds of errors:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<pyshell#230>", line 1, in <module>
>     now("tst_2.csv")
>   File "D:\test_DUAL_up_to_RoleMap_official_edition - Copy\kb_test_manipulation.py", line 84, in now
>     res = json.loads(new_supercl)
>   File "C:\Users\NOTEBOOK2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
>     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
>   File "C:\Users\NOTEBOOK2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
>     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
>   File "C:\Users\NOTEBOOK2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
>     obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
> ```

Any ideas how I should store and/or read the data so I could properly access `col3`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract nested JSON embedded as string in Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34092808/extract-nested-json-embedded-as-string-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: What's the string `json.decode` is passed?

Comment: The exact string is:

    string = [{'mama': 0.5}, {'tati': 0.5}]  <class 'str'>

And it seems that:
    
    for x in string:
        x.replace("'", '"')

does not turn the single quotes into double quotes...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you saved the initial DataFrame it was already storing column 3 as strings.  Your csv actually looks like this:

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   value1  0.5     {'key1': 0.2}
1   value1  0.5     {'key2': 0.3}

                    # Note this column is string.
```

Therefore when you read it, `col3` is giving you a `str` object instead of a `dict` as you might expect.

if there's no explicit reason for you to store `col3` as a string representation of the dictionary, store only the value.  You should update `row1['col3']` to reflect this instead:

```
{'col1': 'value1', 'col2': 0.5, 'col3': [0.2, 0.3]}
```

Assuming you only have a dictionary with one key in each of item of `col3`, you can convert it as such:

```
row1['col3'] = [[i for i in v.values()][0] for v in row1['col3']]
```

So that your `df` will now give you only the values of the dictionary:

```
     col1  col2  col3
0  value1   0.5   0.2
1  value1   0.5   0.3
```

After that your `df.to_csv` and `df.read_csv` should be fine.

I feel like there's a more obvious solution to this than I'm missing, so any `pandas` expert please chime in.

Comment: My csv looks like:

`
       col1    col2    col3
0   value1  0.5   [{'key1': 0.2}, {'key2': 0.3}]
`

The thing is that key1 and key2 ARE different and I need to be able to access both (plus their associated values).
Sorry, I will edit my initial post.