# Access a json column with pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a csv file where one column is json. I want to be able to access the information in the json column but I can't figure it out.

My csv file is like

```
id, "letter", "json"
1,"a","{""add"": 2}"
2,"b","{""sub"": 5}"
3,"c","{""add"": {""sub"": 4}}"
```

I'm reading in the like like

```
test = pd.read_csv(filename)
df = pd.DataFrame(test)
```

I'd like to be able to get all the rows that have "sub" in the json column and ultimately be able to get the values for those keys.

Comment: If "add" is in a JSON sub-field, should that row be included as well?  e.g. `{sub: {add: 4}}`

Comment: Yes. Sorry for not being clear on that

Comment: You just changed the JSON field you're searching for from "add" to "sub".  That breaks all the current answers.

Comment: Are there only two levels to the JSON, or can there be an arbitrary number of levels?

Comment: There can be an arbitrary number of levels. Usually it wouldn't go past 2 levels and very rarely past 3 levels. I expect that most of the data I am looking for would show up within the second level

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one approach, which uses the `read_csv` `converters` argument to build `json` as JSON. Then use `apply` to select on the `json` field keys in each row. `CustomParser` taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20683341/2799941).

**EDIT**
Updated to look two levels deep, and takes variable `target` parameter (so it can be "add" or "sub", as needed). This solution won't handle an arbitrary number of levels, though.

```
def CustomParser(data):
    import json
    j1 = json.loads(data)
    return j1

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', converters={'json':CustomParser})

def check_keys(json, target):
    if target in json:
        return True
    for key in json:
        if isinstance(json[key], dict):
            if target in json[key]:
                return True
    return False

print(df.loc[df.json.apply(check_keys, args=('sub',))])

   id letter                 json
1   2      b           {'sub': 5}
2   3      c  {'add': {'sub': 4}}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you read the file in, the `json` field will still be of *str* type, you can use `ast.literal_eval` to convert the string to dictionary, and then use `apply` method to check if any cell contain the key `add`:

```
from ast import literal_eval
df["json"] = df["json"].apply(literal_eval)
df[df["json"].apply(lambda d: "add" in d)]

#  id   letter  json
#0  1       a   {'add': 2}
#2  3       c   {'add': {'sub': 4}}
```

---

In case you want to check nested keys:

```
def check_add(d):
    if "add" in d:
        return True

    for k in d:
        if isinstance(d[k], dict):
            if check_add(d[k]):
                return True

    return False

df[df["json"].apply(check_add)]

#  id   letter  json
#0  1       a   {'add': 2}
#2  3       c   {'add': {'sub': 4}}
```

This doesn't check nested values other than dictionary; If you need to, it should be similar to implement based on your data.