# Parsing a JSON string enclosed with quotation marks from a CSV using Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680272/parsing-a-json-string-which-was-loaded-from-a-csv-using-pandas/20683341), but my CSV has a slightly different format. Here is an example:

```
id,employee,details,createdAt  
1,John,"{"Country":"USA","Salary":5000,"Review":null}","2018-09-01"  
2,Sarah,"{"Country":"Australia", "Salary":6000,"Review":"Hardworking"}","2018-09-05"
```

I think the double quotation mark in the beginning of the JSON column might have caused some errors. Using `df = pandas.read_csv('file.csv')`, this is the dataframe that I got:

```
id  employee                details    createdAt              Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2 
 1      John        {Country":"USA"  Salary:5000           Review:null}"  2018-09-01 
 2     Sarah  {Country":"Australia"  Salary:6000  Review:"Hardworking"}"  2018-09-05
```

My desired output:

```
id  employee                                                       details   createdAt
 1      John                 {"Country":"USA","Salary":5000,"Review":null}  2018-09-01 
 2     Sarah  {"Country":"Australia","Salary":6000,"Review":"Hardworking"}  2018-09-05
```

I've tried adding `quotechar='"'` as the parameter and it still doesn't give me the result that I want. Is there a way to tell pandas to ignore the first and the last quotation mark surrounding the json value?

Comment: the problem is not with quote, it is with comma, while reading csv all the entries separated by comma are considered as next column

Comment: @Gahan single columns in a CSV can contain commas. The issue probably is the enclosing `"` on the string, causing the commas to be interpreted as new columns rather than part of a dictionary structure

Comment: @roganjosh , I tried, the structure is too responsible for it as quote enclosed `"{"` and then `Country` without quote and then `":"` in quote and then `USA"` and comma encountered which interpreted it as next column value

Comment: I suspect it can only be solved with regex, which rules me out of helping sorry :/

Comment: @roganjosh agreed with regex suggestion

Comment: I completely agree with that, either it needs to have supported format of input or must be parsed with regex

Comment: Instead of trying to parse this, you should rather not use a mix of two badly-interacting metaformats (CSV, JSON) to write the data in the first place. Just use JSON all the way as a default. If you must use this, you need to escape quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative approach you could read the file in manually, parse each row correctly and use the resulting `data` to contruct the dataframe. This works by splitting the row both forward and backwards to get the non-problematic columns and then taking the remaining part:

```
import pandas as pd

data = []

with open("e1.csv") as f_input:
    for row in f_input:
        row = row.strip()
        split = row.split(',', 2)
        rsplit = [cell.strip('"') for cell in split[-1].rsplit(',', 1)]
        data.append(split[0:2] + rsplit)

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
print(df)
```

This would display your data as:

```
  id employee                                            details   createdAt
0  1     John      {"Country":"USA","Salary":5000,"Review":null}  2018-09-01
1  2    Sarah  {"Country":"Australia", "Salary":6000,"Review"...  2018-09-05
```

Comment: Yes I'm doing something similar to that: read the file as raw text, then do modification so that the JSON format is readable by pandas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your file
With

```
   df = pd.read_csv('e1.csv', index_col=None )

print (df)
```

Output

```
     id    emp                                            details      createdat
0   1   john    "{"Country":"USA","Salary":5000,"Review":null}"  "2018-09-01" 
1   2  sarah  "{"Country":"Australia", "Salary":6000,"Review...   "2018-09-05"
```

Comment: could you specify what more tricks you did, tried your solution and it throws exception: `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 2, saw 6`

Comment: Hi, I tried using `header=None` but it still gives me the same result.

Comment: `index_col` is `None` by default so your above solution is equivalent to what the OP has already tried.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a better way by passing a regex to `sep=r',"|",|(?<=\d),'` and possibly some other combination of parameters. I haven't figured it out totally.

Here is a less than optimal option:

```
df = pd.read_csv('s083838383.csv', sep='@#$%^', engine='python')
header = df.columns[0]
print(df)
```

Why `sep='@#$%^'` ? This is just garbage that allows you to read the file with no sep character. It could be any random character and is just used as a means to import the data into a `df` object to work with.

`df` looks like this:

```
                       id,employee,details,createdAt
0  1,John,"{"Country":"USA","Salary":5000,"Review...
1  2,Sarah,"{"Country":"Australia", "Salary":6000...
```

Then you could use `str.extract` to apply regex and expand the columns:

```
result = df[header].str.extract(r'(.+),(.+),("\{.+\}"),(.+)',
                                expand=True).applymap(str.strip)

result.columns = header.strip().split(',')
print(result)
```

`result` is:

```
  id employee                                            details     createdAt
0  1     John    "{"Country":"USA","Salary":5000,"Review":null}"  "2018-09-01"
1  2    Sarah  "{"Country":"Australia", "Salary":6000,"Review...  "2018-09-05"
```

If you need the starting and ending quotes stripped off of the `details` string values, you could do:

```
result['details'] = result['details'].str.strip('"')
```

If the `details` object items needs to be a `dict`s instead of strings, you could do:

```
from json import loads
result['details'] = result['details'].apply(loads)
```