# Python/Pandas: read nested JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am reading a data table from an API that returns me the data in JSON format, and one of the columns is itself a JSON string. I succeed in creating a Pandas dataframe for the overall table, but in the process of reading it, double quotes in the JSON string get converted to single quotes, and I can't parse the nested JSON.

I can't provide a reproducible example, but here is the key code:

```
myResult = requests.get(myURL, headers = myHeaders).text
myDF = pd.read_json(myResult, orient = "records", dtype = {"custom": str}, encoding = "unicode_escape")
```

Where `custom` is the nested JSON string. Try as I might by setting the dtype and encoding arguments, I cannot force Pandas to preserve the double quotes in the string.

So what started off as:

```
"custom": {"Field1":"Value1","Field2":"Value2"}
```

gets into the dataframe as:

```
{'Field1':'Value1','Field2':'Value2'}
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680272/parsing-a-json-string-which-was-loaded-from-a-csv-using-pandas) which suggests using a custom parser for `read_csv` - but I can't see that this option is available for `read_json`.

I found a few suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39491420/python-jsonexpecting-property-name-enclosed-in-double-quotes) but the only one I could try was manually replacing the double quotes - and this causes fresh errors because there are apostrophes contained within the nested field values themselves...

The JSON strings are formatted correctly within `myResult` so it's the parsing applied by `read_json` that's the problem. Is there any way to change that or do I need to find some other way of reading this in?

Comment: when you say nestet json how deep is it nested? Your DataFrame has only two dimensions, so if its double-nested it only can save it as you have shown. Can you provide the JSON String?

Comment: You now have a dictionary...just use it as a dictionary, unless you need to perform string operations on it?

Comment: OK thanks guys - at least I haven't missed a simple option to force it in as-is. Yes I can use it as a dictionary