# How to get rid of string format in Json output from csv

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, csv

How to get rid of the string format for the data from the JSON format.
for example :

```
json = [{"data" :"abc", "data1" :{"a" : 1,"b":2}, "data2" :{"c" : 3, "d":4}}]
```

what I am getting is

```
{"data" :"abc", "data1" :"{"a" : 1,"b":2}", "data2":"{"c" : 3, "d":4}"}
```

I dont want this " " in the dictionary for values  ("{"a" : 1,"b":2}")

the code I'm using to get the data from the CSV is shown below

```
df = pd.read_csv('gen.csv')  
data = df.to_dict('records')
print(data)
```

[image]

Comment: How your csv looks like?

Comment: The string that you posted after "What I am getting is" is not a valid python statement.

Comment: @SuperNoob     Sorry that was a mistake. Now I changed... please look into it.

Comment: @lojza         CSV file will be looks like  **data** as header and "abc" as cell below the data header.  data1 is another header, "{a:1,b:2}" is the value for that header.... data2 is another header, and "{"c":3,"d":4}" is value for that header.

Comment: @Sreevalsan You are still not being clear. Post your gen.csv file. And how are you getting this: ```{"data" :"abc", "data1" :"{"a" : 1,"b":2}", "data2":"{"c" : 3, "d":4}"}``` line? And what do you expect this line to be?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680272/parsing-a-json-string-which-was-loaded-from-a-csv-using-pandas

Comment: @lojza         I don't have a problem as the  CSV is loaded with the data like that. But while reading it back, I'm getting it all in a string format. I want the data, how I appended it. Here dictionary is also getting in a string format. I don't want that. Is there any way that I can read or format is back to the original ?