# Read csv with json column which is nested multiple times into dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the following csv file with a json column `data`. The json data is a little bit complicated and I can't unwrap it the way I want. My goal is to get some data from `configuration` into columns and the corrosponding values from `readings` into the row as value. I found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680272/parsing-a-json-string-which-was-loaded-from-a-csv-using-pandas) but I can't go deeper in the nested data to extract the id and the value with the solutions customized to my data.

The data I have:

```
system;datetime;data;
ACD;19.10.2021 11:24:00,000;{"id":"device1","type":"dataValues","payload":{"deviceId":"device1","start":"2021-10-19 11:23:00.000","end":"2021-10-19 11:24:00.000","configuration":[{"name":"DD51","id":1},{"name":"VV22","id":2}],"detectors":[{"readings":[{"reading":{"count":8}}],"id":1},{"readings":[{"reading":{"count":2}}],"id":2}]}};
ACD;19.10.2021 11:25:00,000;{"id":"device1","type":"dataValues","payload":{"deviceId":"device1","start":"2021-10-19 11:24:00.000","end":"2021-10-19 11:25:00.000","configuration":[{"name":"DD51","id":1},{"name":"VV22","id":2}],"detectors":[{"readings":[{"reading":{"count":7}}],"id":1},{"readings":[{"reading":{"count":4}}],"id":2}]}};
```

What I want:

```
system;datetime;data;DD51;VV22;
ACD;19.10.2021 11:24:00,000;8;2;
ACD;19.10.2021 11:25:00,000;7;4;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `your_file.csv` contains:

```
system;datetime;data;
ACD;19.10.2021 11:24:00,000;{"id":"device1","type":"dataValues","payload":{"deviceId":"device1","start":"2021-10-19 11:23:00.000","end":"2021-10-19 11:24:00.000","configuration":[{"name":"DD51","id":1},{"name":"VV22","id":2}],"detectors":[{"readings":[{"reading":{"count":8}}],"id":1},{"readings":[{"reading":{"count":2}}],"id":2}]}};
ACD;19.10.2021 11:25:00,000;{"id":"device1","type":"dataValues","payload":{"deviceId":"device1","start":"2021-10-19 11:24:00.000","end":"2021-10-19 11:25:00.000","configuration":[{"name":"DD51","id":1},{"name":"VV22","id":2}],"detectors":[{"readings":[{"reading":{"count":7}}],"id":1},{"readings":[{"reading":{"count":4}}],"id":2}]}};
```

Then:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

df = pd.read_csv("your_file.csv", sep=";")[["system", "datetime", "data"]]
df = pd.concat(
    [
        df,
        df.pop("data")
        .apply(literal_eval)
        .apply(
            lambda x: pd.Series(
                {
                    c["name"]: d["readings"][0]["reading"]["count"]
                    for c, d in zip(
                        x["payload"]["configuration"], x["payload"]["detectors"]
                    )
                }
            )
        ),
    ],
    axis=1,
)
```

Prints:

```
  system                 datetime  DD51  VV22
0    ACD  19.10.2021 11:24:00,000     8     2
1    ACD  19.10.2021 11:25:00,000     7     4
```

Comment: What is the system, datetime, data for right next to pd.read_csv? Do you specify the columns seperately?

Comment: @Gobrel Yes, I specified columns that I want to keep from the CSV (the last column in CSV is all NaN - I want to discard it)